# convert unknown vector location into logical form of N

Tags: matlab, vector, logic

Let say i have a location of the vector=[3; 4 ;10]. I want to convert the vector into logical form of 20 row where row 3,4 and 10 equal to 1 and the rest is zero.

i put the argument like this

```
N=20;
LOC=[3;4;10];  %location of the original point
LOGIC= % 20 logical rows where only row 3,4 and 10 equal to 1
```

What will be the function of LOGIC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iwant = zeros(20,1) ;
loc = [3 4 10] ;
iwant(loc) = 1 ;
iwant = logical(iwant) ;
```

Comment: Thanx Siva for your help